# How to convert array key values into percentages

Tags: php, arrays

So i've got an array that looks something like of:

```
Array ( [Safari] => 13 [Firefox] => 5 )
```

How do i a make a new array that looks like :

```
Array ( [Safari] => 72.2% [Firefox] => 27.7% )
```

using a neat php function?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `array_sum()` to get the total, then iterate over the values returning the new value.

```
$total = array_sum($share);

foreach($share as &$hits) {
   $hits = round($hits / $total * 100, 1) . '%';
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9MSU7O).

If you have >= PHP 5.3 it can be a tad more elegant with an anonymous function.

```
$total = array_sum($share);

$share = array_map(function($hits) use ($total) {
   return round($hits / $total * 100, 1) . '%';
}, $share);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CgoPsc).

Comment: @Carlos Cheers, keep 'em coming :)

Comment: +1 Very clean code. I want more of such code on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2):

```
    $array=array ( 'Safari' => 13 ,'Firefox' => 5 );
    $tot=array_sum($array);

    foreach($array as $key=>$value){
       $result[$key]=number_format(($value/$total)*100,1).'%';
    }

    print_r($result); //Array ( [Safari] => 72.2% [Firefox] => 27.7% )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = Array ( 'Safari' => 13, 'Firefox' => 5 );
$total = array_sum($array); # total sum of all elements
$onePercent = $total / 100; # we want to know what value represents 1 percent
array_walk($array, create_function('&$v', '$v /= '.$onePercent.'; $v .= " %";')); # we walk through the array changing numbers to percents
var_export($array);
```

If you want to have your result in second `array` leaving $array not touched, you can use `array_map` instead of `array_walk`

You also might want to use `sprintf` to set precision of float values that represent percent, because my code would output:

```
array (
  'Safari' => '72.2222222222 %',
  'Firefox' => '27.7777777778 %',
)
```

It's not hard to figure out how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For PHP 5.3, you can do it like this:

```
$browsers = array('Safari' => 13, 'Firefox' => 5);

$browsers_proportioned = proportionalize($browsers);

function proportionalize ($arr) {
    $total = array_sum($arr);
    $names = array_map(
            function($number) use ($total) { return number_format($number / $total * 100, 1) .'%'; },
            $arr
    );
    return $names;
}
```

Comment: -1 for what? The accepted answer had included the same answer by the time I posted, though it didn't have this item for PHP5.3 when I was adding it. I have essentially the same answer and get a -1? Some logic here please...

Comment: In Laravel i get the following error: *Unsupported operand types* In `function($number) use ($total) { return number_format($number / $total * 100, 1) .'%'; },`

Answer (score 0):

I personnally like when numbers add up to exactly 100 (not almost 100 like 99.99). So with the solution below, the last item uses the rest instead of being calculated like other items:

```
public static function getPercentagesByKeyValue(array $arr)
{
    $ret = [];
    $nbItems = count($arr);
    $i = 1;
    $sum = array_sum($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $number) {
        $percent = round($number / $sum * 100, 2);
        if ($i === $nbItems) {
            $percent = 100 - (array_sum($ret));
        }
        $ret[$key] = $percent;
        $i++;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```